# Last few characters missing in Codeigniter REST API, json Response

Tags: api, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter REST API, and i am having a response code like this

```
$this->response(array('error' => 'Items could not be found'),403);
```

It works correctly in local machine, But on server i get an output like this

```
{"error":"Items could not be foun
```

the last few characters are missing

The actual output should be like this

```
{"error":"Items could not be found"}
```

Comment: What is the "Codeigniter REST API"? Do you mean Phil Sturgeon's library, or something else?

It's not an official part of the CI release, so we'll need to kow

Comment: This is the API http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Comment: You should check your PHP error logs to look for clues.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem with that REST_Controller. This could be a bit of a hack, but this worked for me.

1. Open REST_Controller.php
2. Locate and delete the following code (at the end of the `response` function):

   ```
   if ( ! $this->_zlib_oc && ! $CFG->item('compress_output'))
   {
       header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
   }
   ```

Then it started showing the complete json response.

Comment: I also had same problem and i solve it like this...But one thing i don't understand is that my system was working earlier without this change from last one year and suddenly i got this issue. How it was working earlier???