# Codeigniter Rest Server fail to output longer JSON

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, server

Does anybody know why 
$this-response($somearray, 200); 
Can't output a long JSON? (Or long arrays)
For example I can output DB result if I limit query to last 10 rows but if I limit it to 100
JSON gets trimed and in my client app I get 'unexpected end of input'. If I change above statement in simple 
echo json_encode($somearray);
It works flawlessly.

I am sorry. I need to clarify my question. I am using 
https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

```
function transits_get()
{
    $sessionId = $this->input->get_request_header('Sessionid', TRUE);
    $transits = $this->Transit_model->get_transits( $sessionId );

    if($transits)
    {
        //$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        //$this->output->set_output(json_encode($transits)); //works
        //echo json_encode($transits); //works
        $this->response($transits, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code //Does not work

    }

    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'There is no transit records in the database!'), 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your php code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, and I have lots of JSON data (+- 250 records):

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

As found in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218450/last-few-characters-missing-in-codeigniter-rest-api-json-response), you can do the following:

1. Open REST_Controller.php
2. Locate and delete the following code (at the end of the response function):

   ```
   if ( ! $this->_zlib_oc && ! $CFG->item('compress_output')) {
       header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
   }
   ```

Comment: That works too. But what I need is to use $this->response method because I really like how it works except it trims longer JSON and make it invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've found what was the problem.
I simply commented out the code in REST_controller that sets content length.
Now it works but I am still wondering why strlen($output) is not as same length as output JSON for larger JSON files and it is ok for short ones.

```
// If zlib.output_compression is enabled it will compress the output,
    // but it will not modify the content-length header to compensate for
    // the reduction, causing the browser to hang waiting for more data.
    // We'll just skip content-length in those cases.
    if ( ! $this->_zlib_oc && ! $this->config->item('compress_output')) {
        //header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In libraries folder, line no. 267 of REST_Controller.php file, comment the following code. it's working.

```
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
```